# Question on decay constant

Tags: radiation, radioactivity, neutrons

I have a model of the radioactivity of a target which is undergoing Neutron Spallation. The Protons are incident upon the target for approximately 200 hours.

Within the model, over the course of these 200 hours, I have assumed that the activity constant $$ (which is some sort of average of the activities of the radioisotopes present) stays constant.

My question is whether this is a correct assumption. If I have a target undergoing Neutron spallation, of course there are many isotopes in the target and in the environment being Neutron activated. Would this lead to a (more than negligible) change in the overall activity $$?

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: So you are spallating neutrons with other neutrons? I usually think is spallation sources using protons (like the (SNS).

Comment: Oh dear. That's an unpleasant mistake. I will correct it. You are correct, we use protons

Comment: So it would seem to me that the initial population of daughter products formed is defined by the beam-target parameters. As time goes on several things may happen including the decay chains of the various daughters, and the spallation products of any daughter products that reach a 'significant' concentration. In general, these are straightforward but detailed calculations to perform.